# Copy text in Libre Office Writer

Tags: libreoffice, clipboard, text-editor

If I have a Writer document that is a numbered list of instructions, and I highlight a chunk of text, or even just a single word in a line of the list, and copy it to the clipboard, go to another program, i.e. gedit, and paste the copied text, the number of the item/line that the text was originally copied from gets pasted as well, even if it was not highlighted to copy.

Can this behavior be changed?

Comment: my bad, I mean gedit

Comment: I also seen this. I think this mainly happens by worng selection or text copied from protected odt files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember from old days I used to work with MS Office under Windows that this also used to be the case with MS Word and Notepad.

So I doubt it can be changed as you wanted probably because it is deep-rooted in the logic of word-processing programs.

However, as a **workaround**, you can **click on the Numbering icon on the Toolbar to turn numbering off before copying text**, and then click on it again to turn it back on, or press Ctrl+Z to undo this last action.